# FullCalendar - Bloquear drag and drop na criação de novos eventos

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, drag-n-drop, calendario

Olá,

Estou com uma dúvida na função drag n drop no Full Calendar. Eu estou fazendo um projeto web e preciso limitar o uso em algumas funções, como por exemplo, limitar o horário de agendamento (no meu caso em 1 hora de duração) e preciso desabilitar o recurso de arrastar e soltar no momento da criação do novo evento. Li a documentação no site e não consegui compreender bem como fazer. Alguma ideia de como fazer isso? Muito obrigado.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                defaultDate: Date(), //pega a data atual
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek', // limita a view para a semana
                defaultTimedEventDuration:'01:00:00',
                dragScroll: false,
                eventDurationEditable: false,
                navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                droppable: false,
                editable: false,
                eventStartEditable: false,
                eventLimit: false, 

           })
       })
```

Answer (score 0):

Unica maneira que consegui foi em fullcalendar.min.js procurar por

```
selectionFootprint = _this.computeSelection(origHitFootprint, hitFootprint);
```

e substituir por

```
selectionFootprint = _this.computeSelection(origHitFootprint, origHitFootprint);
```

assim ele só vai ler a "clicada" inicial e vai ignorar onde seu mouse parou